# Run browser on notification click

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to receive message containing Title and url from Firebase Cloud Message, show notification with these title and url and after clicking on this notification, open this url in browser.
I wrote this code:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String url, String MessageTitle) {

    Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);



    //Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(MessageTitle)
            .setContentText(url)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

But after clicking on notification app is opened, but not the browser. What is my error?
Thanks

Comment: from the code it looks like you are just showing the notification in "sendNotification" but you are not handling that notification then anymore?

Comment: OK, then how can I handle these notifications onclick?